# VS Code/Ruby, Go To Symbol In File match not behaving same as Go To File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, textmate2

I am a long-time Textmate user for Ruby on Rails, but since they have not updated in so long, I've been messing with Visual Studio Code.

Both Textmate and VS Code have a Find Symbol in File and Find File.  However, VS Code's pattern search is not in sync, a space matches an underscore in Find in File, but does not in Find Symbol.

For example, if I have a few methods in a Ruby file called "my_cool_method", "my_cooler_method" and "my_coolest_method".  I then hit the key combination for Find Symbol In File (Shift-Command-O).  I can type in "cool" and they all match.  However, if I type in "cool[space]" the list disappears.  With Find In File (Command-P), that does not happen, spaces and underscores are the same.  This "cool[space]" will match a file named "cool_foo" and "cool_bar", but not the Search Symbol In File.  It's so much easier to NOT have to type in the underscore, like in Textmate.

Is there a way to do this myself?  Is there package that has better search symbol syntax?  I already have the ruby-symbols package.

Thank you